# Int values on BarChart

Tags: android, android-studio, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I want the values on my bar chart to be integers. I only managed to find out how to modify the values represented on the axes with ValueFormatter, but this didn't affect the values on the chart. Here's what I currently have:

[image]

And here's my code:

```
HorizontalBarChart barChart = findViewById(R.id.bar_chart);

    ArrayList<BarEntry> yValues = new ArrayList<>();
    SharedPreferences appData = getSharedPreferences("app_data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String[] supermarkets = new String[appData.getAll().size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : appData.getAll().entrySet()) {
        int value = (Integer)entry.getValue();
        BarEntry e = new BarEntry(i, value, 3);
        yValues.add(e);
        supermarkets[i] = entry.getKey();
        i++;
    }

    BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(yValues, "Supermarkets");
    dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    BarData data = new BarData(dataSet);

    barChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    barChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);

    barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    barChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);

    barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0);
    barChart.getAxisRight().setAxisMinimum(0);

    barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new LabelFormatter(supermarkets));
    barChart.getXAxis().setGranularity(1);
    barChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

    barChart.setData(data);

public class LabelFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {
    private final String[] mLabels;

    LabelFormatter(String[] labels) {
        mLabels = labels;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return mLabels[(int) value];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to add an ValueFormatter to the YAxis returning the value as a string as follows:

```
barChart.getYAxis().setValueFormatter(new IntegerFormatter());
```

Using this simple class:

```
public class IntegerFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {
    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public MyAxisValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0");
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return mFormat.format(value);
    }
}
```

I use the DecimalFormat for extra commas. For example "1234567" should be drawn as "1,234,567". For details look up the Specification [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). [Source](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-AxisValueFormatter-interface)

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't work :( It only modified the values on axes, which I don't care about:
https://ibb.co/eF9Xic

Comment: @KorbiOranssi maybe this will help: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can customize only dataset or chartdata, in my case I choose data because it covers every dataset.

```
BarData data = new BarData(set1);
data.setValueFormatter(new IntegerFormatter());
```

Create new class

```
public class IntegerFormatter extends ValueFormatter {
    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public IntegerFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0");
    }

    @Override
    public String getBarLabel(BarEntry barEntry) {
        return mFormat.format(barEntry.getY());
    }
}
```